# unexpected output with comma operator

Tags: c, if-statement

I wrote a program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
      int x=3;
       if((x)==1,2,4,5,6)
               printf("number found in the list\n");
       else
               printf("Number not found \n");

      return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the output to be "Number not found " but it is "Number found in the list " why it is so

Comment: See [What does the comma operator `,` do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18444099/1708801), it has the lowest precedence.

Comment: This is the same as `if (6) { ... } else {...}`

Comment: C does not support list types. The "comma" is called for a good reason **operator**, not just being a syntax element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expecting `(x) == 1,2,4,5,6` to be evaluated as "`x` is equivalent to *one of* `1`, `2`, `4`, `5`, or `6`", but that's not how the comma operator works.  This is *actually* evaluated as `(x)==1`, then `2`, then `4`, then `5`, and then finally `6`.  Since `6` is not `0`, the condition evaluates to `true` and the first branch is taken.

You'll either need to write

```
if ( x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 4 || x == 5 || x == 6 )
```

or, you'll need to use a loop:

```
int list[] = {1,2,4,5,6};
size_t listSize = sizeof list / sizeof *list;
int found = 0;

for ( size_t i = 0; !found && i < listSize; i++ )
  found = (x == list[i]);

if ( found )
{
  printf( "Number found in list\n" );
}
...
```

Answer (score 5):

The `==` operator has higher precedence than `,`, therefore the if-clause evaluates to

```
if (((x) == 1),2,4,5,6)
```

which is always true since the last "element" of the comma operator "counts" (`6`).

From the C11 standard:

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a `void`
>   expression [...]. Then the right operand is evaluated; **the result
>   has its type and value**.